# What is the different between classes prop in mui and className prop when you insert style in to them?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Any idea what is the difference between classes prop in mui and className ? since booth does the same thing as far as I can tell, please note am not asking about the classes variable in the component which might cause a confusion

```js
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      '& > *': {
        //margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
      },
      padding: 0,
    },
 
 const SomeComponent: React.FC<Props> = () => {
 const classes = useStyles();

 return (
 <div>
  <NativeSelect  className={classes.nativeSelect} classes={classes.nativeSelect}>
  </div>
 )
 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` usually applies styles to the root element while `classes` can target descendant elements or components or even their states. E.g. `NativeSelect` component renders an icon component, you can pass an `icon` class to the `classes` object, or apply styles when the component is `disabled` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Prop `className` is used to add styling to the element, while `classes` is used to Override or extend the styles applied to the component.

So basically, you can create another `class` into your `stylesheet` and apply it into `className` like

```
.new_class{
color:red;
}
```

but to override existing classes like `.MuiRating-root` you have to use `classes` prop